# Why do we consider pressure for perfect gas?

Tags: pressure, gas

In **Equation of state** formula  for perfect  gas we have :

PV=nRT

So we know perfect  gas is a gas in which particles don't have any contact  with  each other. So logically  there shouldn't  be any pressure  in this situation .

Sorry  for poor English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressure is due to the gas molecules contacting the container not each other

Answer (score 1):

The particles of a gas do have contact with each other. But it is axiomatic, of an ideal gas, that any collisions between them are perfectly elastic. This implies there are negligible attractions between the particles and no energy is lost during a collision.